# Get Tuple Type in Roslyn Analyzer

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm writing a Roslyn analyzer and have come across the need to know the type of a tuple. I've retrieved the `TypeInfo` and in the debugger I can see there is a TupleElements hanging off the Type which would be exactly what I need. However it appears only to be accessible by casting to a `TupleTypeSymbol`

```
((Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbols.TupleTypeSymbol)typeInfo.Type).TupleElements
```

TupleTypeSymbol is inaccessible due to it's protection level so the cast is not possible. Is there some other way to access the information?

I have much the same question in the scenarios where my type is an open generic: is there some way to access the type information of the generics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the tuple types you just need to convert your type to `INamedTypeSymbol` and take from it the underlying tuple type: `(type as INamedTypeSymbol)?.TupleUnderlyingType`, after that you will get the normally `ITypeSymbol` of a closed generic type, and finally, just take generic type arguments: `(type as INamedTypeSymbol)?.TupleUnderlyingType.TypeArguments`
- If you want to get info about an open generic type parameters, `T1` and `T2` in the `Gen<T1,T2>` for example, you actually can do the same thing: cast your type to `INamedTypeSymbol` and take `TypeParameters` from it, if type is open or closed generic type